# Redis cli works - both not any NodeJS Redis client

Tags: node.js, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-redis, ioredis

1. I have followed this guide: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/ to install the following: Windows sub-system, Ubuntu and Redis Server and everything seems to work via the Ubuntu-terminal and the redis-cli in Windows. I can set and get values. But my NodeJS clients don't work/can't connect (Only the very first time?).
2. I have install the following NPM Redis client: redis (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).

> ```
> const redis = require("redis");
> const client = redis.createClient();
>  
> client.on("error", function(error) {
>   console.error(error);
> });
>  
> client.set("key", "value", redis.print);
> client.get("key", redis.print);
> ```

And first time it worked out (It could set and read the key named "key")! But then never since!? I have tried close and open the Ubuntu terminal, restart the redis server etc. but nothing seems to help.
The redis-cli works all the time from the ubuntu terminal - it is only the NodeJS client which suddenly doesn't work.

3. I have also tried to install another client: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis But the issue remains and is the same. I connect like this with this client:

> ```
> const Redis = require("ioredis");
> const redis = new Redis({
>     port: 6379, // Redis port
>     host: "127.0.0.1", // Redis host
>     family: 4, // 4 (IPv4) or 6 (IPv6)
>     db: 0,
> });
>
> // ioredis supports all Redis commands:
> redis.set("foo", "bar"); // returns promise which resolves to string, "OK"
>
> // Or ioredis returns a promise if the last argument isn't a function
> redis.get("foo").then(function (result) {
>     console.log(result); // Prints "bar"
> });
> ```

Again, first time it did work with the first Redis client and I didn't set any authentication/credentials...

4. I have not changed a single line in the default conf file.
5. I have just tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 (before I was running 18.04) and to install Redis from scratch again - But the result is the same: Redis cli work but none of the NodeJS clients (not even first time now).

It throws the exception and right after I can catch the "reconnecting" and "connect" event - and it is then running these steps in a loop, over and over again. So it seems like it is able to connect but something disconnect it immediately afterwards?

6a. I get this error message (the NPM: Redis):

> ```
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
>   errno: -4077,
>   code: 'ECONNRESET',
>   syscall: 'read'
> }
> AbortError: Ready check failed: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
>     at RedisClient.flush_and_error (D:\Workspace\GitKraken\tradebutlercommander\node_modules\redis\index.js:297:23)
>     at RedisClient.connection_gone (D:\Workspace\GitKraken\tradebutlercommander\node_modules\redis\index.js:602:14)
>     at RedisClient.on_error (D:\Workspace\GitKraken\tradebutlercommander\node_modules\redis\index.js:345:10)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Workspace\GitKraken\tradebutlercommander\node_modules\redis\index.js:222:14)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
>     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
>   code: 'UNCERTAIN_STATE',
>   command: 'INFO',
>   origin: Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
>     errno: -4077,
>     code: 'ECONNRESET',
>     syscall: 'read'
>   }
> }
> ```

6b. or now I get this error message when using the NPM: ioredis:

> ```
> [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: read ECONNRESET
>     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
>     at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:129:14)
> ```

7. My entire Redis-log looks like this:

> 14151:C 09 Nov 20:32:56.542 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting
> oO0OoO0OoO0Oo 14151:C 09 Nov 20:32:56.543 # Redis version=4.0.9,
> bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14151, just started 14151:C
> 09 Nov 20:32:56.543 # Configuration loaded

```
14152:M 09 Nov 20:32:56.546 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
14152:M 09 Nov 20:32:56.546 # Server initialized
14152:M 09 Nov 20:32:56.546 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
14152:M 09 Nov 20:32:56.546 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
14152:M 09 Nov 20:32:56.546 * Ready to accept connections
14152:M 09 Nov 20:47:57.089 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
14152:M 09 Nov 20:47:57.092 * Background saving started by pid 14157
14157:C 09 Nov 20:47:57.103 * DB saved on disk
14157:C 09 Nov 20:47:57.104 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
14152:M 09 Nov 20:47:57.193 * Background saving terminated with success
14152:M 09 Nov 22:52:57.784 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
14152:M 09 Nov 22:52:57.785 * Background saving started by pid 14158
14158:C 09 Nov 22:52:57.794 * DB saved on disk
14158:C 09 Nov 22:52:57.794 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
14152:M 09 Nov 22:52:57.886 * Background saving terminated with success
14152:M 09 Nov 23:07:58.080 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
14152:M 09 Nov 23:07:58.081 * Background saving started by pid 14159
14159:C 09 Nov 23:07:58.089 * DB saved on disk
14159:C 09 Nov 23:07:58.090 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
14152:M 09 Nov 23:07:58.182 * Background saving terminated with success
14152:signal-handler (1604949420) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
14152:M 09 Nov 23:17:00.243 # User requested shutdown...
14152:M 09 Nov 23:17:00.243 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
14152:M 09 Nov 23:17:00.248 * DB saved on disk
14152:M 09 Nov 23:17:00.248 * Removing the pid file.
14152:M 09 Nov 23:17:00.248 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
14182:C 09 Nov 23:17:01.275 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
14182:C 09 Nov 23:17:01.275 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14182, just started
14182:C 09 Nov 23:17:01.275 # Configuration loaded  

14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.276 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.276 # Server initialized
14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.277 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.277 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.277 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
14183:M 09 Nov 23:17:01.277 * Ready to accept connections
14183:M 09 Nov 23:32:02.032 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
14183:M 09 Nov 23:32:02.033 * Background saving started by pid 14195
14195:C 09 Nov 23:32:02.037 * DB saved on disk
14195:C 09 Nov 23:32:02.037 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
14183:M 09 Nov 23:32:02.134 * Background saving terminated with success
14183:signal-handler (1604976838) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
14183:M 10 Nov 06:53:58.489 # User requested shutdown...
14183:M 10 Nov 06:53:58.489 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
14183:M 10 Nov 06:53:58.500 * DB saved on disk
14183:M 10 Nov 06:53:58.500 * Removing the pid file.
14183:M 10 Nov 06:53:58.500 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
14218:C 10 Nov 06:53:59.528 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
14218:C 10 Nov 06:53:59.528 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14218, just started
14218:C 10 Nov 06:53:59.528 # Configuration loaded

14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 # Server initialized
14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
14219:M 10 Nov 06:53:59.530 * Ready to accept connections
14219:signal-handler (1604985108) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
14219:M 10 Nov 09:11:48.604 # User requested shutdown...
14219:M 10 Nov 09:11:48.604 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
14219:M 10 Nov 09:11:48.612 * DB saved on disk
14219:M 10 Nov 09:11:48.612 * Removing the pid file.
14219:M 10 Nov 09:11:48.612 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
14252:C 10 Nov 09:11:49.645 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
14252:C 10 Nov 09:11:49.645 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14252, just started
14252:C 10 Nov 09:11:49.645 # Configuration loaded

14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 # Server initialized
14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
14253:M 10 Nov 09:11:49.648 * Ready to accept connections
14253:signal-handler (1604987303) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
14253:M 10 Nov 09:48:24.076 # User requested shutdown...
14253:M 10 Nov 09:48:24.076 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
14253:M 10 Nov 09:48:24.089 * DB saved on disk
14253:M 10 Nov 09:48:24.089 * Removing the pid file.
14253:M 10 Nov 09:48:24.089 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
14280:C 10 Nov 09:48:25.139 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
14280:C 10 Nov 09:48:25.139 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14280, just started
14280:C 10 Nov 09:48:25.139 # Configuration loaded

14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 # Server initialized
14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
14281:M 10 Nov 09:48:25.144 * Ready to accept connections
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be a permission problem. Is redis-cli running as administrator? Is node?

Comment: We have a simular problem (econnreset) when reading value by key from redis (using redis package). Have you found solution or reason?